# How to check if a point $P(x,y)$ lies inside a rounded rectangle?

Tags: geometry

Given a rectangle which can have one or more rounded corners with a certain given radius, how to check if a point $P(x,y)$ lies inside this rounded rectangle?

The radius can be different for each corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be the unrounded rectangle, $R'$ the rounded rectangle, and $r$ the radius of the rounded corners.

1. Check if $P$ is contained in $R$. If not, then $P$ is not in $R'$.
2. If $P\in R$, then check if $P$ falls within any of the four squares of side length $r$ contained within $R$ and sharing a corner with $R$. If not, then $P\in R'$.
3. If $P$ falls in one of those squares, compute the distance from $P$ to the corner of the square contained in the interior of $R$. If that distance is greater than $r$, then $P\notin R'$. Otherwise, $P\in R'$.